# Controlling subplot font properties at once but independently

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to control the properties for subplot's title in a way that is independent of other font properties while using latex as interpreter (I don't think this last part is relevant, but just in case). Here is a sample code:

```
% Figure handle
fig1 = figure;

% Subplot 1
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(rand(100,1))
xlabel('$x$ label')
ylabel('$y$ label')
title('First subplot')

% Subplot 2
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(rand(100,1))
xlabel('$x$ label')
ylabel('$y$ label')
title('Second subplot')

% Setting global properties
set(findall(fig1,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',14)
set(findall(fig1,'-property','Interpreter'),'Interpreter','Latex')
set(findall(fig1,'-property','TickLabelInterpreter'),'TickLabelInterpreter','Latex')
```

When I do this, I can set the size and interpreter for axis labels, tick labels, and subplot titles. This makes the title to have the same style as those other objects.

Is there a way to control the titles properties independently to make them slightly bigger and bolder, for example, so they are easily distinguishable from axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`set`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) instruction can be applied to an array of graphic handle, so if you want to modify properties of all your titles, just gather their handles in an array first, then use the [`set`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) command on the handle array.

So in your example, replace your

```
% ...
title('First subplot')
% ...
title('Second subplot')
% ...
```

by:

```
% ...
ht(1) = title('First subplot')
% ...
ht(2) = title('Second subplot')
% ...
```

You now have an array of handles `ht` to your titles. Now to modify them all in one batch, without modifying anything else:

```
set( ht , 'FontSize',18, 'FontWeight','bold')
```

---

Similarly, you could regroup handles of other objects to assign their properties in one go:

```
% build a collection of xlabel array
hxlabel = [hax(1).XLabel hax(2).XLabel] ;
% Set their label and interpreter all at once
set( hxlabel , 'String' , '$x$ label' , 'Interpreter','Latex' )
```

This will apply the same `xlabel` to all the subplot, and set their interpreter to latex at the same time.

The same reasonning can be applied for the `ylabel`, or any other common property accross many objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make the titles bigger, you can set it when calling the `title` command:

```
title('First subplot', 'FontSize', 14, 'FontWeight', 'bold')
```

If you want to have more control over the font sizes of the individual objects, you have to store the axis handle (which are created upon creating a subplot):

```
ax1 = subplot(211)
ax2 = subplot(212)

% set the properties of the title:
ax1.Title.FontSize = 14;

% set the properties of the XAxis:
ax1.XAxis.FontSize = 7;
```

To see what settings you can change, just call the handle in the command window, which will give you more details:

```
>> ax1.Title

ans = 

  Text (First subplot) with properties:

                 String: 'First subplot'
               FontSize: 14
             FontWeight: 'bold'
               FontName: 'Helvetica'
                  Color: [0 0 0]
    HorizontalAlignment: 'center'
               Position: [50.0001 1.0139 0]
                  Units: 'data'
```

---

If you want to set the properties of the titles in different axes (subplots) in a figure, you could store the axes in a cell array:

```
ax = {subplot(211), subplot(212)};

plot(ax{1}, rand(100,1));
plot(ax{2}, rand(100,1));

for i=1:numel(ax)
    ax{i}.Title.Fontsize = 14;
end
```

Comment: I am aware of the use of the `title` command. But that requires to set the properties for each `title` (or axis handle) individually. I was trying to find a way of changing the properties of *all* titles at once, like I do with the other properties in my example. Any ideas?

Comment: I had no luck with your new solution. I get the error `No public property Fontsize exists for class matlab.graphics.primitive.Text.`. Maybe this Title.Fontsize property is not present in all Matlab versions? I am using 2015b

Comment: @Looper Oh forgot the capital I think, does it work with `ax{i}.Title.FontSize`?

Comment: You are right, the capital S was needed. But this solution still has a lot of problems: (1) it doesn't seem to play well with multiple plots in the same axis, even after specifying `hold on` and `plot(ax{i}, ....)`, it only plots the last `plot` in each axis, except in the last one in which you get all plots (weird, I know). (2) to get the titles, legends and axis labels working, you need to specify the axis in for *each one* of them, i.e. `title(ax{1},'First')`, etc, so not much value in automatizing the properties at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I got to solve this by setting the following "global" properties (placed at the end of the example above):

```
% Setting global properties
set(findall(fig1,'-property','Interpreter'),'Interpreter','latex')
set(findall(fig1,'-property','TickLabelInterpreter'),'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
set(findall(fig1,'-property','Title'),'FontSize',14)
set(findall(fig1.Children,'-property','TitleFontSizeMultiplier'),'TitleFontSizeMultiplier',1.8)
```

Few things to note. The property `Children.TitleFontSizeMultiplier` in the figure handle scales whatever you have as `FontSize`. However, the specification `FontSize` cannot be placed before `Interpreter`, as this seems to lock any further font size specifications.

If you want bold face when using the `latex` interpreter, you need to specify that directly in the title: `title('\textbf{First subplot}')`. Changing the property `Children.TitleFontWeight` between `normal` and `bold` doesn't seem to have any effect.